# Item in where query source

Tags: sql, oracle10g, oracle-apex, oracle-xe

Hi I'm a newbie to the oracle apex and I'm trying to create a dynamic page that let the user (the logged one) see only "his" record I tried  in the source query (P101_USERNAME is the username item on the login page)

```
select * from user u where u.username=v('P101_USERNAME')
```

And this

```
  Select * from user u where u.username=:P101_USERNAME
```

But I got the no data found error I think I'm doing the things the wrong way.. So is there a way to create a page that let the user see only the record linked to his username(or primary key) and hide the other?

Comment: btw - welcome to using a very powerful software development tool

Comment: You'll also find more robust APEX forum community at 
https://community.oracle.com/community/database/developer-tools/application_express

Answer (score 1):

That username field is only relevant for the life of the login process.

Throughout the application you should refer to `:APP_USER`

See list of available substitution strings
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39147/concept_sub.htm#BEIHCJBG

Comment: The username and password for the login is selected from the user table so I can't use APP_USER

Comment: @Ivano You ALWAYS can (and should) use `:APP_USER`. `P101_USERNAME` is just the name of an input field on the login page, nothing more.

Comment: Yes I created a function for the login to use user and pass that came from a table the question is can I use an item in the where condition of a source page? And how?

Comment: Ok ty for your time I guess I hot it APP_USER get the user that logged the application I'm running the moment I log in

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using APEX 5, you can now get the User from the APEX$SESSION application context. [here](https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2015/11/apex-5-application-context/)

You also can use function APEX_APPLICATION.g_user [here](https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2014/02/dont-always-call-v/)